# Microsoft Azure HDinsight Ambari Sqoop and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, azure, hadoop, sqoop, azure-hdinsight

Trying to import data from postgres into hdfs on Microsoft Azure HDInsigt. Now i started with a very simple command if listing dbs

```
sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc.postgresql://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy --username myuser --password mypassword
```

i get the following error

```
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string: jdbc.postgresql://52.178.204.150:4321
    at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:191)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:257)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:44)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
```

I tried adding the following args

```
--libjars=/usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc4.jar
--driver org.postgresql.Driver 
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager
```

These still do not help the HDInsight manual only gives an example to use Microsoft SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is wrong: `jdbc.` should be `jdbc:`

Comment: Well that's embarrassing that seems to have been the problem not sure how i missed that. Now on to the driver not found issue. Thank you.